# EmberJS: why are destroyed records committed back to the server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Sometimes in my Ember app I create some records with createRecord, but I don't want to store all of them on the server. So I call `destroy` on the objects I don't need before calling `store.commit()`. Yet, they are sent to the server nonetheless. How do you prevent this?

I have tried to `commit` in the "next" Ember run but it does not work either:

```
... do some clean up ...
Ember.run.next(self, function() {
    self.store.commit(); // The destroyed objects are committed nonetheless
});
```

Thanks!

PJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deleteRecord` is the appropriate method to call on `DS.Model` instances. A complex state is managed by `DS.Store`, and as such it coordinates deletions separately from the low-level `destroy` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher. For some reason I thought deleteRecord was going to issue a DELETE command to the server. So I did not want to use it. But you are right it does work and it does not send a DELETE. Thanks!